# A Simple function identity

Tags: analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

Show the following identity,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\nabla(\frac{f}{G})|^2\,G\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla f|^2\,G^{-1} \,dx \,-\,\int_{\mathbb R^d} f^2(\Delta \Phi) \, G^{-1} dx
$$

Here,

$G(x)=(2\pi)^{d/2}e^{-|x|^2/2}$,

$\Phi(x)=-log(G(x))=|x|^2/2+log(2\pi)^{d/2}$

(See that $\Delta \Phi =d$)

$f$ is a compactly supported smooth function and $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f=0$.

I can get the first term in R.H.S. but second term is not coming. I cannot even see where do I use conditions on $f$ as the rest terms involve $f^2$ and $\nabla f^2$.

Please help,

Regards,

Harish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int | \nabla (f/G) |^2 G = \int \left| G^{-1} \nabla f - G^{-2} f \nabla G \right|^2 G \\
= \int \left( |\nabla f |^2 G^{-1} - 2 (f \nabla f) \cdot (G^{-1}\nabla G) G^{-1} + f^2 |G^{-1}\nabla G|^2 G^{-1} \right) \\
= \int \left( |\nabla f |^2 G^{-1} + \left[ \nabla(f^2) \cdot (\nabla (-\log{G})) + f^2 |\nabla(-\log{G})|^2 \right] G^{-1} \right)
$$

Note also the following identity on functions:
$$
\nabla \cdot ( f^2 \nabla(-\log{G}) G^{-1} ) = \nabla(f^2) \cdot \nabla(-\log{G}) G^{-1} + f^2 \Delta(-\log{G})G^{-1} + f^2 \nabla(-\log{G}) \cdot \nabla(G^{-1}) \\
= \nabla(f^2) \cdot \nabla(-\log{G}) G^{-1} + f^2 \Delta(-\log{G})G^{-1} + f^2 \nabla(-\log{G}) \cdot(-\nabla G) G^{-2} \\
= \nabla(f^2) \cdot \nabla(-\log{G}) G^{-1} + f^2 \Delta(-\log{G})G^{-1} + f^2 \nabla(-\log{G}) \cdot \nabla(-\log{G})G^{-1}
$$

Integrating this identity over $\mathbb{R}^d$, the left-hand side vanishes because $f$ is continuous with compact support, and then it is easy to see that substituting the resulting identity between integrals into the previous equation gives the requested result. (So in fact, the identity is considerably more general than your special case: any $G>0$ bounded below on compact sets will do, and $\int f$ is also not used.)